# Magento 2 : How to Set custom Discount from controller?

Tags: magento2, discount

I am developing a module which set discount to total, Whenever customer will press **Get Discount**.

I can able to reduce **Subtotal** and **GrandTotal** in customer quote, **Also my quote table is getting updated**.

Check my controller below.

```
public function execute()
{
        echo "<pre>";
    
        $label          = 'My Custom Discount';
        $discountAmount = 10;              
        
        $quoteSession = $this->salesQuote->getQuote()->getData();
        $quoteId = $quoteSession['entity_id'];
        
        $quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
       // print_r($quote->getData()); exit;
       
       
         $quote->setSubtotal($quote->getSubtotal() - $discountAmount);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal() - $discountAmount);
       
       $quote->setSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getSubtotalWithDiscount() - $discountAmount);
       $quote->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($quote->getBaseSubtotalWithDiscount() - $discountAmount);
       
       $quote->setGrandTotal(30);
       $quote->setBaseGrandTotal(30);
       
       $quote->save();
```

But how can I render my Updated Grand Total at **Cart Page** as well as other further steps like checkout, Invoice, etc etc?

I am stuck here, No idea what is next step !!

Any help would be really great.

Comment: I need this to and would be very pleased if anybody could answer this question

Comment: can you refer this link https://github.com/Turiknox/magento2-custom-total/tree/master/app/code/Turiknox/CustomTotal

Comment: Any Solution about that from controller?

Comment: Aaa... Not yet :)

Comment: any update on this @anonymous

Answer (score 0):

First, create new file `sales.xml` inside `etc` folder with the following code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Sales:etc/sales.xsd">
    <section name="quote">
        <group name="totals">
            <item name="affiliate_discount" instance="Vendor\Module\Model\Total\Quote\CustomTotal" sort_order="420"/>
        </group>
    </section>
</config>
```

Next, create the file `Vendor\Module\Model\Total\Quote\CustomTotal.php` with the code below:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Total\Quote;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule;

class CustomTotal extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal
{
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return $this|bool
     */
    public function collect(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
    )
    {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);
        //Set your custom total here!
        $total->addTotalAmount();
        $total->addBaseTotalAmount();
        $total->setBaseGrandTotal();
        return $this;
    }

}
```

Hope it help!

Comment: Thanks, But i already know this way, I would like to perform same thing from controller.

Comment: I used same code but when ever user adds 2 or 3 or 4 products to cart then collect function is calling 2 or 3 or 4 times depends on number of products. How can i restrict to collect totals only once?

Comment: @anonymous, you got the way to update from controller? I need to update there

Comment: how we can update the quote from controller? any update?

Comment: anyone who has performed the same task through controller?

Comment: @VishalParkash, have you done via controller?

Comment: @VinodKumar No, I did not find any solution to work using Controller