# Magento 2: Set custom discount price to existing cart/quote in controller

Tags: magento2, module, cart, extensions, discount

I would like to set a custom discount price to an existing cart/quote in my controller and found some other people that had this question but none of them got answered:

[I want to add discount to existing quote using controller file Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/218832/i-want-to-add-discount-to-existing-quote-using-controller-file-magento-2/218835#218835)

[Magento 2 : How to Set custom Discount from controller?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217739/magento-2-how-to-set-custom-discount-from-controller)

To give you an example, if the customer clicks a button in the cart he will get a random discount price. But now how can I achieve to add this specific disount price to the cart and quote in the controller?

Comment: why you do not use Cart Rules?

Comment: Because I need to set a specific custom discount price, that isn't the same every time. As I calculate a discount in my controller and then I want to set this calculated discount price.

Comment: Do you want to use Cart rules concept means showing your custom discount at below of  total section  of cart

Comment: Ah, ok. Yes I want to show the custom discount below the total section of the cart.

Comment: any updates on this?